# How can i get value before symbol '-' in PHP

Tags: php

Sorry for my English.
I have a a small question:
There is a variable such as :

```
$a = '123-abc';
```

My question is, how can i get the number 123 in variable $a ?

Thanks for help :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// what you want is $ret[0]
$ret = explode('-', $a);
echo $ret[0];
```

Comment: May be it also worth adding `2` as a third explode argument

Answer (score 3):

```
substr($a, 0, strpos($a, '-'));
```

or

```
preg_match('~^[^-]+~', $a, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    In the following example, we have declared a string variable and assigned it a phone number in this format: 001-234-567678. So now we want to loop and get value before each hyphens in string (phone number)

    $phone_number = "001-234-567678";
    //Using the explode method
    $arr_ph = explode("-",$phone_number);

    //foreach loop to display the returned array
    foreach($arr_ph as $i){
        echo $i . "<br />";
    }

Output
001
234
567678


    For more information
    https://www.jquery-az.com/php-explode-method-to-split-a-string-with-3-examples/
```